# If I use a number as a loop stopper, how do I make sure my program won't initialize that number as a max or min?

Tags: java, initialization

Here's what my program is supposed to do: 
This is a program with a loop that lets the user enter a series of integers. The user should enter -99 to signal the end of the series. After all the numbers have been entered, the program should display the largest and smallest numbers entered.

My code is working but right before it stops it initializes either the max or min as the -99, instead of the last intended integer in the series, then ends. What can I do to stop that?

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create variables 
    int maxInt = -1000;         //number that will be the largest initialized very low
    int minInt = 1000;          //number that will be the smallest initialized very high
    int input = 0;              //to hold the user's integer entry

    //loop for the user to enter as many integers as they want
    while(input != -99)
    {
        //General Instructions and initialization of input
        System.out.println("Enter an integer. "
            + "When you are finished, please enter -99.");
        input = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(input > maxInt)
        {
            maxInt = input;
        }
        else if(input < minInt)
        {
            minInt = input;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Your lowest number is: " + minInt);
    System.out.println("Your highest number is: " + maxInt);

    keyboard.close();
}
```

Comment: Check `input` immediately after `input = keyboard.nextInt();`, and `break` if its value is `-99`.

Answer (score 1):

Your input is assigned inside your while-loop thus not yet -99 when the loop starts. Therefore runs the loop with -99 and then stops at the end.

```js
while (input != -99) {
  System.out.println("Enter an integer. " + "When you are finished, please enter -99.");
  input = keyboard.nextInt());

  if (input == -99) {
    break;
  }
  if (input > maxInt) {
    maxInt = input;
  } else if (input < minInt) {
    minInt = input;
  }
}
```

Now the loop ends when there is a input of -99 due to the break statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the input value before assigning the maxInt or minInt variable for -99 if it is your sentinel control value.

Example

```
if ( input > maxInt && input != -99 )
{
    maxInt = input;
}
else if ( input < minInt && input != -99 )
{
    minInt = input;
}
```